# how to group duplicate object keys with own values

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object

I need to make a array of object just like bellow example

```
[{
    UOM: ['DITEC', 'ENGLISH', 'SOMTHING']
}, {
    BIT: ['DITEC', 'ENGLISH', 'SOMTHING']
}, {
    LMU: ['DITEC', 'ENGLISH', 'SOMTHING']
}, {
    BCS: ['DITEC', 'ENGLISH', 'SOMTHING']
}, {
    HND: ['DITEC', 'ENGLISH', 'SOMTHING']
}]
```

This is what i have tried so far [<kbd>**JSFIDDLE**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/DPdq2/)

```
var division = [];
var batches = [];
var obj = {};

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

    obj[data[i].D_Code] = data[i].Default_Batch;
    division.push(obj);

}

console.log(division);
```

I want pure javascript solution or angular solution.No More Jquery Please

Comment: @Jack See the fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/DPdq2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you would typically group items together, using an object:

```
var divisionCodeGroups = {};

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
{
    var key = data[i].D_Code;

    if (!divisionCodeGroups.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        divisionCodeGroups[key] = [];
    }
    divisionCodeGroups[key].push(data[i].Default_Batch);
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/DPdq2/3/)

Comment: Fabulous,++1 use for hasOwnProperty

Answer (score 0):

A little tweak in for loop will work.

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if(obj[data[i].D_Code]===undefined){
        obj[data[i].D_Code] = [data[i].Default_Batch];
    }else{
        obj[data[i].D_Code].push(data[i].Default_Batch);
    }     
}
```

Here is the **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shivaraj/YZ2c5/)**

Hope it helps.